# How to create Autocomplete - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to create autocomplete but can't get how to do it yet. I have a local json file with an array which I should search through. I listed all the data from it, but now I dont know how to do it. This is what I tried:

```
private _url = 'assets/json-data/restaurants.json';

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

     getRestaurants () {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

and this is my app.component.ts:

```
  restaurants: any[] = [];
  filteredRestaurants: any[] = [];
  searchValue: string;

  constructor(private restaurantsService: RestaurantsService){}

    ngOnInit() {

  }

  search() {
      this.restaurantsService.getRestaurants()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      this.restaurants = response.results;
      for (const r of this.restaurants) {
        if (r.name.indexOf(this.searchValue) > 0) {
          this.filteredRestaurants = response.results;
        } else {
          this.filteredRestaurants = [];
        }
      }
      // this.restaurants = response.results;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
  }
```

In my html, I put:

```
<div class="search-input-box">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keyup)="search()" class="search-input">

    <div *ngIf="filteredRestaurants && filteredRestaurants.length > 0" class="ac-list">
      <ul *ngFor="let r of filteredRestaurants">
        <li>{{ r.name }}, {{ r.address.city }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I guess I can't do it like this because I don't have an actual `searchValue` on backend? How can I do it with only this json file?

EDIT: I edited my question, this is what I tried, but it doesnt work like i want it. I tried going through every object in my array in response and looking if the value is correct

EDIT 2: Solved it with this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'restaurant' })
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(restaurants: any, searchValue: any): any {
    if(searchValue == null) return restaurants;

    return restaurants.filter(function(restaurant){
      return restaurant.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're after is something often referred to as "Typeahead" - where you type into a search box, and using the similarity between what you have typed, and items in your JSON array, the search box attempts to 'suggest' what you're typing.

I recommend using a library of pre-made Angular components from [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead). Amongst this library is a Typeahead component.

I use this library in most of my Angular projects - the documentation on the Typeahead component should be detailed enough to help you.

Comment: I know about this one, I used it in one project myself too, but now I would like to create my own typeahead (autocomplete, w/e its called), thanks for the try

Comment: Well then let me try again.

Your restaurant service is making a HTTP call to a .JSON file - This will not magically search through the data in the file and return filtered results.

It's better off for your restaurant service to load the data from the JSON file and store it into an array. The service will then perform a filter on the array object using the searchValue.

Regarding your comment `//can't use ngModel here`, you most certainly need to be using ngModel right there. And upon changes of the model you need to call restaurantsService.getRestaurants

Comment: It is important to note that ngBootstrap typeahead only accept displaying a list of strings and does not support list of object. making it rather useless for real use-case scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

How I would do it is:

One input, one div (empty at first, but it get filled once you start typing in the input).

Once you start typing in the input, you take the value from the input, and you use that value to filter through your restaurants, finding all the values which include your input value.

So, something like:

```
<input #inputValue (onkeyup)="filterValues()" />
    <div *ngIf='yourNewArray'>
    <span *ngFor="item of yourNewArray">
      {{item}}
    </span>
    </div>
```

and your .ts

```
filterValues() {
 this.yourNewArray = restaurants.filter(restaurant => restaurant.includes(inputValue);
}
```

Maybe this is just a pseudo code, I haven't tested it. I just hope to bring you on the right track :)

Comment: For angular 5, you have to use:
let item of yourNewArray

and change onkeyup to keyup

Answer (score 0):

**TS File**

```
public filterIndustry(event){
   let filter =  event.target.value.toString().toUpperCase();
   let data = [];
   if(filter == ''){
    this.Desired_Industry = Desired_Industry;
    return
   }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Desired_Industry.length; i++) {
    if(this.Desired_Industry[i].toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
      data.push(this.Desired_Industry[i])
    }
    }
    this.Desired_Industry = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.Desired_Industry.push(data[i])
    }
    
  }
```

***HTML File***

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="filterIndustry($event)" matInput placeholder="Search">
 <div class="dropDown-Options" *ngFor="let industry of Desired_Industry">
  <mat-option [value]="industry">
  {{ industry }}
  </mat-option>
 </div>
```

Enjoy